# You cannot set up an iAd Workbench account using this Apple ID

Tags: app-store-connect, iso

what problem for this one?
You cannot set up an iAd Workbench account using this Apple ID. Try again using a different Apple ID that is not connected to an iCloud, MobileMe or .Mac account.

Please help me
thanks by ketan patel[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now anyone can sign up for Apple iAd.

If you don't have an iTunes Connect Account, sign up with any non-icloud account, like your Google Admob account.

If you have an iTunes Connect Account, then login to access iAd.
If you still get this error you may need to update or complete your tax and banking contracts.